# How to create dynamic directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this html and directive:

html:

```
<div id="box">
    <button test>Add</button>
</div>
```

and this directives:

```
// directive for button
tarefasApp.directive('test', function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(){
            // create anchor
            el      = document.createElement('a');
            el.id   = 'test2';
            el.innerHTML = 'Click me';
            att     = document.createAttribute('test2');

            // set attribute to anchor
            document.getElementById('test2').setAttributeNode(att);

            // insert the anchor inside div#box
            document.getElementById('box').appendChild(el);
        });
    }
});

// directive for the dynamically created anchor
tarefasApp.directive('test2', function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(){
            alert('it worked!');
        });
    }   
});
```

When I click `<button test></button>`, the first directive creates a `<a id="test2" test2>Click me</a>` and append it to `<div id="box"></div>`. So far so good. But when I click `<a id="test2" test2>Click me</a>` it doesn't call the `directive test2` and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you already have element with the same id, for this to work you would need to have a new id generated each time.

Comment: @HarishR i think you miss understood. the only element with id is the `div` and the dynamically created anchor `a#test2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

I made an example of how to make a new HTML element, and "compile" it with the angular $compile once you add it in the DOM

http://codepen.io/AntouanK/pen/irkHL

```
var tarefasApp =
angular.module('tarefas', []);

// directive for button
tarefasApp
.directive('test',
['$compile',
function($compile){

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        element
        .on('click',function(){

          var newAnchorEle;

          //  make the new element
          newAnchorEle = document.createElement('a');

          angular.element(newAnchorEle)
          .attr('anchor', '')
          .text('test');

          //  append it in the parent element
          element.parent().append(newAnchorEle);
          //  compile the new HTML
          $compile(newAnchorEle)(scope);
        });
      }
    }
}]);

// directive for the anchor
tarefasApp
.directive('anchor',
['$compile',
function($compile){

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        console.log('anchor made');

        setInterval(function(){
          element.toggleClass('hidden');
        },500);
      }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I just used your code and added `element.on('click')` function inside `link` in `directive('anchor'..` and it worked like a charm. thanks